# Cron task can't find mysql server

Tags: cron, ee-1.13

I'm manually running a cron task (RocketWeb Subscriptions) through the Magento admin Scheduler section. Everything runs fine except it keeps failing when trying to save the transaction. I keep getting the error:

`Next exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (1)' in /{ROOT}/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144`

even though everything else in Magento seems to work just fine. I'm able to view and use my store, and get into the admin section to work. I'm running this on a Vagrant box with a private IP; I tried changing the DB settings in local.xml to point to that private IP, even tried 127.0.0.1 but it comes back with the same result. Any ideas why this behavior would occur?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about this is about SQL server and a third party module

Comment: The support at Rocket Web is excellent. You can open a ticket with them and they will get back to you very quickly.

Comment: turned out to be a config issue. my local.xml had the `<host>` set to localhost:port instead of having a separate `<port>` attribute.

Comment: Please put your answer in the answers section and accept it to close out the posting